# How to animate the axis label using `gganimate`?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am actually very amazed to see I cannot quickly find a guide to how to do this. Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

dt <- lapply(seq(10), function(i){
    mean = i
    label = paste0("T = ", i)
    dt = data.table(x = seq(0, 50, length.out = 100))
    set(dt, j = "y", value = dt[, dlnorm(x, meanlog = log(mean), sdlog = 0.2)])
    set(dt, j = "frameN", value = i)
    return(dt)
}) %>% rbindlist

print(dt)

p <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "x", breaks = c(0, 1)) +
  transition_manual(frameN)

animate(p)
```

I want the `breaks` and `labels` of `scale_x_continuous` to follow my own definitions:

```
arr_breaks <- c(1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 7)
arr_labels <- paste0(seq(10, 100, 10), " kg")
```

And then

- `breaks = arr_breaks[1], labels = arr_labels[1]` for frame 1
- `breaks = arr_breaks[2], labels = arr_labels[2]` for frame 2

...

- `breaks = arr_breaks[10], labels = arr_labels[10]` for frame 10

No matter how I do it I got errors. Any idea?

Comment: Based on your update, I think you'll have better luck adding a `geom_text` layer with the desired positions / labels near the bottom of your chart. gganimate primarily animates *data* rather than scales (except for `view_*`, but even those functions take reference from changes in data from frame to frame).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @z-lin noted, gganimate is not currently set up (to my knowledge) to animate scales with different breaks. The effect could be closely approximated using geoms, and with some more work you could probably make an exact visual match to a changing scale.

```
breaks_df <- data.frame(

frameN = c(1:10),
  arr_breaks = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 7),
  arr_labels = paste0(seq(10, 100, 10), " kg")
)

p <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_segment(data = breaks_df, color = "white",
               aes(x = arr_breaks, xend = arr_breaks,
                   y = -Inf, yend = Inf)) +
  geom_text(data = breaks_df, vjust = 3, size = 3.5, color = "gray30",
            aes(x = arr_breaks, y = 0, label = arr_labels)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "x", breaks = c(0)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  transition_manual(frameN)
animate(p, width = 600, height = 250)
```

[image]